# Segmentation fault by pushing back 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I have a function that takes a numeric string and assigns each element into a single dimension vector:

```
void insert(vector<int> &matrix, string s)
{
for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
matrix.push_back(s[i]-'0');
}
```

Then, at my *main* function I declare a 2D vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix;
```

Now for example I try to execute the function:

```
insert(matrix[0],"12345");
```

It will simply give me error **Segmentation fault**, and I don't know why.

How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: Because your `matrix.size()` is 0, so accessing `matrix[0]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Start by creating http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I think because you are declaring your 2Dvector like

> vector<vector> matrix;

so by declaring like this your matrix is of size 0.

Since your matrix is empty you cannot access elements from that. Instead init your 2d vector with some default values like 0 and give a try.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void insert(vector<int> &matrix, string s)
{
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
        matrix.push_back(s[i]-'0');
}

int main()
{
    int n=2,m=2;
    vector<vector<int> > matrix(n, vector<int>(m));
    
    insert(matrix[0],"12345");
    for (auto i:matrix)
    {
        for (auto j:i)
        {
            
            cout << j;
        }
    }

}
```

I am not sure if this is what you are expecting from your insert func